# Disable dates in Kendo Calendar after the initialization

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have simple Kendo calendar, where I can disable dates at the moment of its initialization:

```
$("#simpleCalendar").kendoCalendar({
    disableDates: ["sa", "su"]
});
```

How could I disable specified dates, after the initialization of this calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`disableDates`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-disableDates) accept a function also to determine which dates to be disabled.

```
$("#simpleCalendar").kendoCalendar({
    disableDates: function (date) {
       //Test date 
       var disabled = [2,4,6,8];
       return date && disabled.indexOf(date.getDate()) > -1;
    }
});
```

You can also use [setOption](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#methods-setOptions) to change the initial DatePicker configuration.

```
$("#simpleCalendar").data("kendoCalendar").setOptions({
    disableDates: ["sa", "su", new Date(2015, 9, 12), new Date(2015, 9, 22)]
});
```

Comment: How can I call this function again, after initialization of the calendar, to replace previous disable dates, to others?

Comment: @YuriyN. the function will call automatically and disable all dates which doesn't passes the test condition

Comment: At the moment of initializing the calendar. But I need to call this function every time I need it, not only once.

Comment: Of course, for example, I select a library from a list, then, I call function `libraryDisabledDays`, which disable all dates in the calendar, when the selected library doesn't work.

Comment: It works, though, it must be `kendoCalendar`, instead of `kendoDatePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to re-initialize the calendar. Before doing that you need to clear content of previous calender

```
$("#changeBtn").click(function(){
    $("#calendar").empty();
    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
        disableDates: ["mo", "tu"]
    });
});
```

here is a working demo
http://dojo.telerik.com/IMOlI

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, Satpal was the first, but your solution also possible.